# How to read .dat file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, load, asciidoc, matlab-load, ecgi

I am trying to read an ECG signal from PTB dataset, the file extension is ".dat" ,i am using Matlab function for that:

```
load('s0484_re.dat');
```

where "s0484_re.dat" is the file name
but i am getting an error like this:

Error using load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file
s0484_re.dat
"�����\�".

Error in signal2image (line 8)
load('s0484_re.dat');

how i can read this file correctly?
Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension `.dat` can be used for many different types of binary data file and doesn't tell you what format the data is in.

By searching on 'PTB dataset` I [found the information](https://physionet.org/content/ptb-xl/1.0.1/) that the data files in this dataset are in 'WaveForm DataBase (WFDB) format', and by [searching mathworks.com for 'WFDB'](https://uk.mathworks.com/search.html?c%5B%5D=entire_site&q=wfdb&page=1) I found a few links including a [toolbox for handling WFDB files](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox). Try this toolbox, and update your question if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: it worked,but now i am having another issue, when i use wfdb2mat it should generate a file with the extension .mat, but it generates nothing

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question showing your code and describing any steps you've taken to troubleshoot it.

Comment: why wfdb2mat function is generating nothing?
I am using this code to convert dat file to mat and then read the generated file:


'wfdb2mat('/home/salar/Documents/mythesis/Matlab/s0484_re')'
'[tm,signal,Fs,labels] = rdmat('s0484_re.mat');'


i am getting this error:


'Error using rdmat (line 78)'
'Could not open file: s0484_re.mat.hea !'


my question is: why wfdb2mat function is generating nothing?
thank you in advance